# Email - how to simulate absolute positioning

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm trying to place an imagem between two elements, but when it gets to an email client, it doesn't work. 
Is it possible to get an absolute positioning of an element or at least simulate it with float or something else? If not, well... back to the basics then (images) 
 I have several references for a workaround, but none of them worked for me.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title></title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
        #news-wrapper {
            margin: 0 auto;
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 600px;
            font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
            position: relative;
        }

        #news-head {
            height: 117px;
            padding: 50.5px;
            position: relative;
            background-color: #8e8e8e;
        }

        .heading {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 340px;
        }

        .heading h1 {
            color: white;
            font-weight: 300;
            background-color: #713235;
            padding: 9.5px;
            font-size: 24px;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            font-stretch: condensed;
        }

        .image-container {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 263px;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
            bottom: 50px !important;
            position: relative !important;
            left: -3% !important;
            right: 0;
            float: right;
        }

        #news-body {
            width: 100%;
            max-width: 555px;
            margin-top: 0;
            margin-bottom: 0;
            margin-left: auto;
            margin-right: auto;
        }
        p.default {
            color: #4c4c4e;
            font-size: 16px;
            font-weight: 300;
            line-height: 1.81;
        }
    </style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="news-wrapper">
        <div id="news-head">
            <div class="heading">
                <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="image-container">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/263x115" alt="">
        </div>
        <div id="news-body">
            <div style="margin-top: 120px;margin-bottom: 34px">
                <h2 style="color: #713235; font-weight: 300; text-indent: 35px;">VIVAMUS VITAE METUS DOLOR</h2>
                <p class="default" style="text-indent: 35px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc finibus lectus vel elit posuere consequat.
                    Praesent rutrum quam ut mauris pharetra feugiat. Nunc pulvinar malesuada ante, in vestibulum ante interdum
                    eu. Aliquam malesuada aliquam nulla ut suscipit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus
                    et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: You may never see the result you see here in your email. Email clients usually have many restrictions for HTML. Use tables (instead of div) for more assurance. Some email clients even do not support margin and padding.

Comment: As ata said you should stay away from divs unless you are doing hybrid coding. Also the chosen answer will not work on all email clients.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use this CSS for your image container, basically using a margin-top to move it down to the desired position:

```
.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 263px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 60px;
}
```

And if that moves your `#news-body` down too much, you can apply a negative `margin-top` to it, like in the snippet below.

```css
#news-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

#news-head {
  height: 117px;
  padding: 50.5px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #8e8e8e;
}

.heading {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 340px;
}

.heading h1 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #713235;
  padding: 9.5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-stretch: condensed;
}

.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 263px;
  float: right;
  margin-top: 60px;
}

#news-body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 555px;
  margin-top: -40px;;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

p.default {
  color: #4c4c4e;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.81;
}
```

```html
<div id="news-wrapper">
  <div id="news-head">
    <div class="heading">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
    </div>
<div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/263x115" alt="">
  </div>
  </div>
  
  <div id="news-body">
  
  <div style="margin-top: 120px;margin-bottom: 34px">
      <h2 style="color: #713235; font-weight: 300; text-indent: 35px;">VIVAMUS VITAE METUS DOLOR</h2>
      <p class="default" style="text-indent: 35px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc finibus lectus vel elit posuere consequat. Praesent rutrum quam ut mauris pharetra feugiat. Nunc pulvinar malesuada ante, in vestibulum ante interdum eu. Aliquam malesuada aliquam nulla
        ut suscipit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I dont think this will work. Position has very patchy support across all email clients (definitely not in Outlook). I understand you were trying to work with the code provided and this will work on web only.

Answer (score 0):

`margin` may work in this case

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
  <title></title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <style>
    #news-wrapper {
      margin: 0 auto;
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 600px;
      font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
      position: relative;
    }
    
    #news-head {
      height: 117px;
      padding: 50.5px;
      position: relative;
      background-color: #8e8e8e;
    }
    
    .heading {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 340px;
    }
    
    .heading h1 {
      color: white;
      font-weight: 300;
      background-color: #713235;
      padding: 9.5px;
      font-size: 24px;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
      font-stretch: condensed;
    }
    
    .image-container {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 263px;
      margin-top: -50px;
      margin-right: 3%;
      /* maintain position to allow stacking */
      position: relative;
      right: 0;
      float: right;
    }
    
    #news-body {
      width: 100%;
      max-width: 555px;
      margin-top: 0;
      margin-bottom: 0;
      margin-left: auto;
      margin-right: auto;
    }
    
    p.default {
      color: #4c4c4e;
      font-size: 16px;
      font-weight: 300;
      line-height: 1.81;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="news-wrapper">
    <div id="news-head">
      <div class="heading">
        <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image-container">
      <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/263x115" alt="">
    </div>
    <div id="news-body">
      <div style="margin-top: 120px;margin-bottom: 34px">
        <h2 style="color: #713235; font-weight: 300; text-indent: 35px;">VIVAMUS VITAE METUS DOLOR</h2>
        <p class="default" style="text-indent: 35px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc finibus lectus vel elit posuere consequat. Praesent rutrum quam ut mauris pharetra feugiat. Nunc pulvinar malesuada ante, in vestibulum ante interdum eu. Aliquam malesuada aliquam nulla
          ut suscipit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

The email client should be able to parse the `relative` and `absolute` position. It seems like you are trying conflicting positioning by including a `float`.

In the following example, I set the `.image-container` container to relative, remove all floats and the `max-width`, letting it stretch across the screen. Then I set absolute on `.image-container img` and define `top` and `right` positions as necessary. Hope that helps.

```css
#news-wrapper {
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 600px;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
  position: relative;
}

#news-head {
  height: 117px;
  padding: 50.5px;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #8e8e8e;
}

.heading {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 340px;
}

.heading h1 {
  color: white;
  font-weight: 300;
  background-color: #713235;
  padding: 9.5px;
  font-size: 24px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-stretch: condensed;
}

.image-container {
  width: 100%;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  position: relative;
}

.image-container img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -50px;
  right: 40px;
}

#news-body {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 555px;
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-bottom: 0;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

p.default {
  color: #4c4c4e;
  font-size: 16px;
  font-weight: 300;
  line-height: 1.81;
}
```

```html
<div id="news-wrapper">
  <div id="news-head">
    <div class="heading">
      <h1>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="image-container">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/263x115" alt="">
  </div>
  <div id="news-body">
    <div style="margin-top: 120px;margin-bottom: 34px">
      <h2 style="color: #713235; font-weight: 300; text-indent: 35px;">VIVAMUS VITAE METUS DOLOR</h2>
      <p class="default" style="text-indent: 35px;">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nunc finibus lectus vel elit posuere consequat. Praesent rutrum quam ut mauris pharetra feugiat. Nunc pulvinar malesuada ante, in vestibulum ante interdum eu. Aliquam malesuada aliquam nulla
        ut suscipit. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Positioning is buggy and doesn't work in every browser. The same with margin.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/positioning-display/position/

You can use some CSS tags used for box model, but it's really hit and miss.
https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css/box-model/

I can't think of an easy way to suggest what will work in this situation. Email is not front-end design. My suggestion is look over this web site before you continue to give you a better idea what will work in email.

https://www.campaignmonitor.com/css